# Do I need a domain pointing to my server before I can get a SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

So I just followed [this](http://library.linode.com/ssl-guides/commercial-ssl-cert) tutorial and set myself up a SSL certificate for my domain. Though, currently, the domain doesn't point to my server...

Do I need the domain to point to my server before I can request my certificate from GoDaddy? Or can I submit the certificate request, have them return the .crt then point the domain over when it's needed..?

Comment: Not related to your question per se, but an awesome SSL resource: http://www.sslshopper.com/

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you don't need to have a server up for an SSL certificate to be granted. GoDaddy's identity validation procedures may require one, and that I don't know about. But providing proof that you do in fact own the domain you're requesting the SSL certificate for should be sufficient.

Comment: Aight, I've sent of the request. Cheers for the help.